# Use customized date format in list for ComboBox in UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excels spreadsheet I have the following data:

```
       A                B
1   2020-01-06
2   2020-01-07
3   2020-01-08
4   2020-01-09
5   2020-01-10
6   2020-01-11
7   2020-01-12
8
```

I am using a German Excel so the normal date format is `06.01.2020`, `01.07.2020` and so on. 
In order to switch the date format to the above style I `customized` the format with `JJJJ-MM-TT` as in the screenshot below.

[image]

*--- Sorry to only have the screenshot available in German. ---*

All this works fine.

---

Now, I want use the data from `range` `A1:A7` in `ComboBox1` in the `UserForm2`. 
Therfore, I went with this VBA:

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value
End Sub
```

This VBA inserts the list into the `ComboBox1` but it does not use the `customized date`. 
It switches back to the `original date format` looking like this:

[image]

What do I need to change in my VBA so it displays the dates in the same style as in `range` `A1:A7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the job.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Arr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        ' this is English syntax and might be different in German
        Arr(i, 1) = Format(Arr(i, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Next i

    ComboBox1.List = Arr
End Sub
```

The `Initialize` event fires when the form is created, the `Activate` event a little later, when it's activated. Using the `Activate` event, you might `Hide` the form, change the data and `Show` it again with a different list. Unless this is your plan it's more like a source of "unexplainable errors". Therefore I recommend use of the `Initialize` event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I run it the list of dates looks like this: JJJJ-01-TT, JJJJ-01-TT, JJJJ-01-TT, and so on.

Comment: Try the Engling "yyyy-mm-dd". If that doesn't work, look for the German term for the `Format` function. Please let me know here so that I can amend my post accordingly.

Comment: FYI - Explicit format symbols of VBA's `Format()` function always remain in English - c.f. [MS Help Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications).