# VBA userform combobox - how to customize date format from number format?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am trying to display an array in a combobox of a userform. The array is populated with a column of a listobject whose entries are formatted as dates. Within the array the dates are formatted into numbers. I would like the array entries to be displayed as "normal" date formats in the combobox, however, all I get is the date in the number format.

Here's the code I used including a couple of different versions I tried to convert the format (all failed).

How I put the date array together. Below you see the main sub from which I call the array function and the userform:

```
Sub master()
Dim dates_collection As Variant
dates_collection = dates_count()
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    With uf_selection 'userform name      
    'cbo_delivery = combobox
        .cbo_delivery.RowSource = ""
        .cbo_delivery.List = dates_collection 'adding array to combobox
        .cbo_delivery.Text = Format(.cbo_delivery.Text, "dd.mmm.yyyy") '>> not working
        .cbo_delivery.ListIndex = 0
        
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

The corresponding function looks like below. It is deleting all duplicates in the listobject column:

```
Public Function dates_count() As Variant()
Dim data() As Variant
Dim r As Long
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

data = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").ListObjects("tbl_raw").ListColumns("Week End Date").DataBodyRange.Value2

For r = 1 To UBound(data)
    dict(data(r, 1)) = Empty
Next

data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys())
dates_count = data
End Function
```

Note that as another approach I manipulated the initialize sequence of the userform as shown below. Then doing so, I outcommented the `with` sequence in the code above.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        cbo_delivery.RowSource = ""
        cbo_delivery.List = dates_collection
        cbo_delivery.value = Format(DateValue(cbo_delivery.Text), "dd.mmm.yyyy")
        cbo_delivery.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Additionally, I tried the approach presented here: [click link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718422/use-customized-date-format-in-list-for-combobox-in-userform)

Comment: `Format(DateValue(cbo_delivery.Text), "dd.mmm.yyyy")` this one works for me. As long as `cbo_delivery.Text` is in a format that VBA can automatically convert into a `Date` variable.

Comment: @Toddleson thanks for your feedback. I get an error message (error: 13). I used this simpliefed code version: ```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        cbo_delivery.RowSource = ""
        dates_collection = Array("43009", "43016")
        cbo_delivery.List = dates_collection
        cbo_delivery.value = Format(DateValue(cbo_delivery.Text), "dd.mmm.yyyy")
        cbo_delivery.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `cbo_delivery.Text` at the time of execution? If you pause the macro at that line and look at the value in the watch window, what does it say?

Comment: the value of `cbo_delivery` is "". Its a variant/string type.

@Toddleson I ran the code w/o this line `cbo_delivery.RowSource = "" ` to make sure there is no manipulation. same result as indicated above.

As I defined `dates_collection = Array("43009", "43016")` in my simplified example, these should be in line with the type of the combobox...

Comment: `DateValue` will give an error if you try to convert an empty string into a `Date`. If `cbo_delivery.Text` is empty, don't run that line. If it has a value like `"2021-12-09"` then `DateValue` will work and you'll be able to run the line and fill your combobox with `"09.Dec.2021"`

Comment: @Toddleson ok. makes sense. however, I guess my combobox is not empty as I populated it before trying to convert the format: `cbo_delivery.List = dates_collection`

You said there was no problem on your end running the code. Did you use date formats in number such as `43009` instead of `"2017-10-01"`?

Comment: `DateValue` only accepts formatted strings. To convert a number to a date use `CDate`.

Comment: ok, great. this triggers my next (and hopefully last) question on this issue: is there a lean way to convert all elements of an array (which are exclusively numbers) into date formats at once?

Comment: VBA doesn't have any easy array manipulation interfaces like LINQ in VB.NET. So unfortunately, you just have to iterate the whole array and convert them one by one. But you can put that into its own Sub, and tuck it away in a separate code module and then it feels clean.